# Why float not working in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I use Laravel 5.3

I use :

> "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
>
> "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0",
>
> "dompdf/dompdf": "0.7.x@dev",

I get from here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

In config\dompdf.php, I set :

> "DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT" => true,

In my html pdf, I try :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>

        <style type="text/css"> 

            body {  
                font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 9px;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }
            .container {
                background:#fff;
                overflow:auto;
            }

            .left {float:left;}
            .right {float:right;}

        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left">Float left</div>
            <div class="right">Float right</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The float not working

How can I solve it?

**Update** :

The result of pdf is like this :

[image]

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to Dompdf 0.8.0 as it has better float support.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of float.

I use the older version of dompdf in my project. I enable **`DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT`** `true` in `dompdf_config.custom.inc` file. But the float result is overlapping and distorted.

The inline-block is the new and better way than using float left every time. Visit the following w3school link to more info. [CSS Layout - inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following.

```
.container{
    ...
    display : block;
 }
```